# c# console: How to ReadLine without the need of pressing [Enter]

Tags: c#, console-application

My c# console application is used as a login for my c# form application, the problem is, in my c# console app i haven't been able to figure out a way to `ReadLine` without the need of pressing `Enter` because i need to detect whether `F2` or `Enter` is pressed then `ReadLine` without needing user to press `Enter` again. For example, if i wanted to detect if `F2` is pressed i would need to wait until `F2` is pressed until I'm able to `ReadLine`, Hopefully this question was worded in a way that it makes sense, I'm sure you can tell I'm quite a 'noob' at c#.
Example of my problem:

```
static void Main()
{
    var KP = Console.ReadKey();
    if (KP.Key == ConsoleKey.F2)
    {                                    
        //User Presses F2                
    }      
    else if (KP.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        string UserName = ReadLineWithoutPressingEnter();//Just a example
        //ReadLine without needing to press enter again
    }                            
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: your question it not clear ?

Comment: you need to read a line without pressing `Enter` ..is this your question?

Comment: @usmanlqbal Yes that is my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the result from ReadKey and then just do a ReadLine:

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var KP = Console.ReadKey();
        if (KP.Key == ConsoleKey.F2)
        {
            return;               
        }

        string UserName = KP.KeyChar + Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine(UserName);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! This is exactly what i was looking for, have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

You've already found [`Console.ReadKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey(v=vs.110).aspx). That's a start. You'll need to also build a state machine around this function to return a completed string at the end of the line, but this method is the key to making that work. Don't forget to handle things like backspace and delete.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example Try this

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo cki = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
        int i = 0;
        do
        {


            while (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
                Thread.Sleep(250); // Loop until input is entered.
            cki = Console.ReadKey(true);

            if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.F1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User Have Press F1");
                //do some thing
            }

            if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User Have Press Enter");
                //do some thing
            }
            if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.A)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User Have Press A");
                //do some thing
            }

        } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.X);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo e;
        string userName = "";

        while (true)
        {
            e = Console.ReadKey();

            if (e.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (e.Key == ConsoleKey.F2)
            {
                //things to do when F2
            }

            userName += e.KeyChar;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("username: " + userName);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it would. But did you know, a string is immutable and every loop creates one new string object?